# Porque al hacer un proyecto con python en mi escritorio no me funciona pero al hacerlo en mis documentos si?

Tags: python, windows, vscode, opencv, pip

Hola estimada gente de la comunidad, tengo una duda a la cual no le encuentro explicación.

Antes que nada esto me paso con visual studio code y con una maquina windows.

Estaba desarollando un proyecto con "opencv contrib python" usando los comandos de "import cv2".

El asunto es que tenia una imagen la cual corria junto al cv2 pero al momento de ejecutarlo no aparecia nada y me salia error, intente muchas cosas y nada funciono, entonces fue cuando hice el proyecto exactamente igual pero en vez de usar una carpeta en el escritorio como folder, hice uno nuevo en documentos y salio todo a la perfeccion.

Mi pregunta es porque no me salia error en documentos pero si en el escritorio, y si hay alguna manera de crear proyectos y que me funcionen tanto en carpetas que tenga en el escritorio como carpetas que tenga en mis documentos.
De antemano muchas gracias

PD: Adjunto el pequeño codigo:

```
import cv2
imagen=cv2.imread('contorno.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen',imagen)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Trata de ser específico para no poner a otros a adivinar y que puedas recibir respuestas útiles más rápido. "Me salía error", qué error? "Intenté muchas cosas", qué intentaste? Recuerda siempre responder a comentarios yendo a [edit] y aclarando o añadiendo la info correspondiente.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema pero no tengo idea a que se deba el problema, no creo que sea la versión de Python 3.10 que este dando estos problemas pero antes no me pasaba con las versiones anteriores

Comment: Muy probablemente sea la ruta de la imagen

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo por el feedback. Lo tendre en cuenta y lo editare enseguida, soy nuevo en la comunidad y no tenia idea del recorrido. saludos